# How do I get both auto-localized select list enums AND datatables in ABP Framework (abp.io)

Tags: localization, abp

In the ABP framework, the tutorial for version 5.1 says to:

> Use **Enum:enum-type:enum-value** naming convention to localize the enum members.

*e.g. "Enum:BookType:1": "Adventure"*

However, this does not work when using the **abp-select** tag helper.  I can see from the source code for **abp-select** that the expected format is actually:

**Enum:enum-type.enum-toString**

*e.g. "Enum:BookType.Adventure": "Adventure"*

So the documentation is inaccurate, but not a problem, as soon as I changed the resource file enums to the correct format **abp-select** localised the display values as expected.

However, the datatables source code for the Book List in the same tutorial then breaks:

```
        columnDefs: [
            {
                title: l('Type'),
                data: "type",
                render: function (data) {
                    return l('Enum:BookType:' + data);
                }
            }
```

This code expects the enum format to be **Enum:enum-type:enum-value** and as **data** is passed back as an int and not the string representation of the enum, the datatable doesn't show the localised data.

As a work around, I am diverging from the tutorial instructions and binding the datatable to a BookDto where BookType is mapped to a string, not an enum.  Feels a bit cludgy though.

Am I missing something here ABP?

Great product but this tutorial needs updating either way.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue but solved it by updating the localization file `en.json` to match the enum value stored in the database and then changing the `book.component.html` file to match the `abpLocalization` property.

When I followed the official documentation at abp, I got this result:

[First run with fallback string in HTML component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDoKL.png)

**`Acme.BookStore.Application.Shared/Localization/en.json`**

```json
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "Menu:Home": "Home",
    "Welcome": "Welcome",
    "LongWelcomeMessage": "Welcome to the application. This is a startup project based on the ABP framework. For more information, visit abp.io.",
    "Menu:BookStore": "Book Store",
    "Menu:Books": "Books",
    "Actions": "Actions",
    "Close": "Close",
    "Delete": "Delete",
    "Edit": "Edit",
    "PublishDate": "Publish date",
    "NewBook": "New book",
    "Name": "Name",
    "Type": "Type",
    "Price": "Price",
    "CreationTime": "Creation time",
    "AreYouSure": "Are you sure?",
    "AreYouSureToDelete": "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
    "Enum:BookType.0": "Undefined",
    "Enum:BookType.1": "Adventure",
    "Enum:BookType.2": "Biography",
    "Enum:BookType.3": "Dystopia",
    "Enum:BookType.4": "Fantastic",
    "Enum:BookType.5": "Horror",
    "Enum:BookType.6": "Science",
    "Enum:BookType.7": "Science fiction",
    "Enum:BookType.8": "Poetry"
  }
}
```

**`book.component.html`** in the angular project

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
          <h5 class="card-title">
            {{ '::Menu:Books' | abpLocalization }}
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="text-end col col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ngx-datatable [rows]="book.items" [count]="book.totalCount" [list]="list" default>
        <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Name' | abpLocalization" prop="name"></ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Type' | abpLocalization" prop="type">
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{ '::Enum:BookType.' + row.type | abpLocalization }}
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::PublishDate' | abpLocalization" prop="publishDate">
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{ row.publishDate | date }}
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column [name]="'::Price' | abpLocalization" prop="price">
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{ row.price | currency }}
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
      </ngx-datatable>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I have replaced the ":" with a "." as in the localization file.

After change to source-code I get this result:

[Enums now translated correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVl1P.png)

I hope this helps you and others struggling with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. The problem is a mismatch between the declaration of the localization file wrt the usage in the JS code.

In the localization file you can find keys like:

> "Enum:BookType.Adventure": "Adventure"

while in the JavaScript it is used:

```
render: function (data) {
    return l('Enum:BookType:' + data);
}
```

Thus either you change the localization keys as e.g. *"Enum:BookType:Adventure": "Adventure"* (with ':') or you change the code with this function:

```
render: function (data) {
    return l('Enum:BookType.' + data);
}
```

where the '.' is concatenated instead of ':'